# Smallest value of largest angle in finite planar configurations

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Does every set of $n$ points in the Euclidean plane contain three points $A,B,C$ such
that the two segments obtained by joining $A,B$, respectively $A,C$ form an angle
at least equal to $(1-2/n)\pi$ at the point $A$? (Equality is of course achieved by the
vertex set of a regular $n-$gone.)

Pietro Majer's example below can be generalized and shows that $(1-2/n)\pi$ has to be replaced by a somewhat smaller constant (at least for values of $n$ which are large enough). For his example
we have to take $(1-2/6)\pi$ instead of $(1-2/7)\pi$. Is the best possible constant
$(1-a(n))\pi$ asymptotically substantially better, ie. can $na(n)$ become for example arbitrarily large for $n$ large enough? (It is of course obvious that $a(n)$ is decreasing but how fast?)

Update: For $n=5$, one can get arbitrarily close to $(1-1/4)\pi$:
Take a right-angled isocele triangle. Split the right-angled-vertex infinitesimally
along a line parallel to the longest side of the initial triangle and add
an additional point on the symmetry axis very high above the two infinitesimal points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key bound is $(1 - 1/n) \pi$, due to Erdős and Szekeres:

---

[image: Erdos Furedi Quote]

---

The above is an excerpt from this paper:

---

[image: Erdos Furedi Title]

---

The Erdős-Szekeres result is in their 1961 paper, "On some extremum problems in elementary geometry.", Ann. Univ. Sci. Budapest. Rolando Eötvös, Sect. Math. 3-4, 53-62 (1961)
([PDF download link](http://bsmath.hu/~p_erdos/1960-09.pdf)).

Comment: How does the configuration of $8=2^3$ points without angles
greater than $2/3\pi+\epsilon$ look like?

Comment: @Roland: I added a link to the Erdős-Szekeres paper.  Their proof is in Section 4, p.59 ff. I cannot pursue it myself at the moment; sorry. 

Comment: Thank you. By the way, the configuration on $8$ points is easy:
one can split the central point in Pietro Majer's example into 
two infinitesimally close points on a line parallel to a side of
the initial triangle.

Comment:  actually this way we make a new angle  (1−1/6)π...

Comment: I am not sure whether it's just me or whether the link is dead. In any case, [this link](http://bsmath.hu/~p_erdos/1960-09.pdf) seems to work. Here is also [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20190815065808/http://bsmath.hu/~p_erdos/1960-09.pdf).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks, Martin, for providing a correct link.

Answer (score 5):

Consider an exagon obtained from an equilateral triangle by cutting three small equilateral triangles from its vertices. Consider the configuration of the $6$ vertices of the exagon, plus the center of the initial equilateral triangle. It seems to me that with these $7$ points one can't do angles larger than $2\pi/3+\epsilon$.

Comment: Indeed. So what is the best possible constant for a given integer $n$?

Comment: Yes, it seems a beautiful and difficult variational problem.

Comment: Sorry, since I can accept only one answer and since Joseph O'Rourke
mention of the Erdos-Szekeres paper kills the problem completely,
I have changed the accepted answer to his reply.